# Accessing array elements in c

Tags: c, arrays, increment

Below is the code on compiling this code in codeblocks I get the following error message:

`1 value required as increment operator`.

Now I know that `arr++` is not working but I want to know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5},i;

  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n",*arr);
    arr++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> arr++ is not working but i want to know why?

`arr` stores the base address that is `&arr[0]` ***therefore, `arr` always points to the starting position of the array and can't be changed***. that's the reason why `arr++` is invalid and doesn't work.

---

***Solution:***

you can instead use `arr` with the help of `*` (*referencing operator*) operator to print the array elements

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",*(arr+i)); 
    //pointer arithmetic *(arr+i)=*(&arr[0]+i*sizeof(data_type_of_arr))
}
```

here, ***pointer arithmetic*** is helpful to understand

---

or else, in order to print the data instead use the index `i` this way :

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

---

One more way to do it is to *consider a new pointer to `&arr[0]` and increment*.

```
int *p=&arr[0];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    p++;
    //pointer arithmetic *(p)=*((&p)+1*sizeof(data_type_of_arr))
    //NOTE: address of p updates for every iteration
}
```

---

For further reading on **pointer arithmetic** : [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

Answer (score 4):

While arrays can decay to pointers to their first element (which is what happens when you use e.g. `*arr`) it is not a pointer in itself.

You also can not change an array, change where it "points", which is what is wrong with `arr++`, it is roughly the same as `arr = arr + 1` and while `arr + 1` is allowed the assignment back to `arr` is not, you can't change the location of an array.

If you want to do like you do, then you need an actual pointer, initialize it to point to the location of the first element of `arr`, and use the pointer in the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5},i;

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      printf("%d\n",*(arr+i));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

arr++ not working.because of array is constant pointer and you can't increment the address. so alway remember array name represent as base address then If you want to increment then give extra argue with that.see the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The increment operator is applied on the *value* of a variable. The value of an array is its elements, so what would you expect the increment operator to do? Increment each element in the array? The value of a pointer variable, on the other hand, is an address, so the increment operator applies here.

Answer (score -1):

You can't using operator ++ for arrays.
Array is are constant pointer to data and can't be modified.

Comment: As alternative you can access tyo array via index : arr[i] or declare additional pointer int *ptr=arr and increment/decrement it.